# share a property in different functions within a same class in php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, php-5.3

I have this code example, where I am not receiving the value of $something in the passData() function, since null comes, what is happening, this is code example:

```
class ClassName extend X {

     private $something;

     public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', array($this,
         'createText') );
     }

     function createText() {
         $property = 'xthing';
         $this->something = $property;
         return $this->something;
     }

     public function passData() {
         $somethingMore=$this->something;
     }
}
```

i expecting $something get data in function passData()

Comment: It seems like `$something` is null because a value is never assigned to it. Calling `ClassName->passData()` should set `$somethingMore` to `null`. However, if you were to call `ClassName->createText()` and then `ClassName->passData()`, the value of `$somethingMore` should be `xthing`

Comment: @outlaw, Hello, the createText() function is called first, within that function we give value to $something, and I hope you can go to the passData() function, and pass the data to $somethingMore of $somthing